# Interface polymorphism in C#

Tags: c#, .net, polymorphism

I have a code like this:

```
public interface INode
{
    INode Parent { get; set; }
    // ......
}

public interface ISpecificNode : INode
{
    new ISpecificNode Parent { get; set; }
    // ......
}

public class SpecificNode : ISpecificNode
{
    ISpecificNode Parent { get; set; }
    // ......
}
```

This code gives a compilation error, because INode.Parent is not implemented. However, I don't need duplicate Parent properties.
How can I solve this issue?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

I think you're looking for something like this:

```
public interface INode<T> where T : INode<T>
{
    T Parent { get; set; }
}

public interface ISpecificNode : INode<ISpecificNode>
{
}

public class SpecificNode : ISpecificNode
{
    public ISpecificNode Parent { get; set; }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

This is not inheritance / overriding like you get with classes - interfaces do not *inherit* other interfaces, they *implement* them.

This means anything that implements `ISpecificNode` must also implement `INode`.

I would suggest you remove the line

```
new ISpecificNode Parent { get; set; }
```

there is probably no need for it. Alternatively you could look to implement `INode` on an abstract base class, override it with the concrete `SpecificNode` class, and use property hiding to hide the `INode` version of the property.

Comment: There is need. I'd prefer to work with ISpecificNode.Parent without need to cast types.

Comment: Alternately, the answer from Allessandro is a nice and more advanced technique.